# How to generate a random number between 0 and a user-defined integer in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, random, matrix

I'm having a problem with my code, in which I try to generate a number between 0 and a `dim` user-defined variable. The line I'm having problem is:

```
arrayPos = rand()%dim;
```

I already called `srand(time(NULL))` and the arrayPos is getting some wierd numbers like 9.267e-315 and so on.
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty certain this has been asked on Stackoverflow before...

Comment: If you're in C++ and especially C++11 you should avoid `rand()` it should be considered [harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) furthermore using `% dim` does not produce a uniform distribution and should be avoided (the video I linked to explains why)

Comment: Your code should work (somewhat reasonably) as written. 9.267e-315 looks like "random garbage in an uninitialized variable" to me. The problem likely lies elsewhere, in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: How is arrayPos defined? How is dim defined? How did you print things out? etc etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem really was garbage memory, I restarted the computer and it worked like a charm